# How do I delete repeating rows from a table but leave the distinct of them?

Tags: sql, t-sql, rank

Catch is, the entire row is the same.

Table:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Bye
Bye
Good Morning
Good Morning
```

I want to LEAVE:

```
Hello
Bye
Good Morning
```

I know you can use RANK() here but I have never really used it so I'm not too sure.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Can you show the table definition or is this the only column in your table?

Comment: can you select distinct into a new (temp) table, then truncate the original table and repopulate from the temp?  the only thing that would stand in the way of doing that is referential integrity but if you don't have to worry about that, i think it's the easiest way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and then delete everything from the table that does not have a row number of 1:

```
;with cte as
(
  select col,
    row_number() over(partition by col order by col) rn
  from yourtable
)
delete 
from cte 
where rn > 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2deb1/1)

Comment: +1 - sql fiddle looks awesome!

Comment: thanks dude. need 10 mins to accept :)